# Hololens app keeps mapping surroundings and obstructs my holograms

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, spatial, hololens

I'm developing a Hololens App in Unity 2017.0.p5 with Mixed Reality Tollkit and I have this problem.
[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pWzH.jpg). It keeps mapping the surroundings and obstructs my holograms.

Does anyone know how stop drawing these triangles in all the surfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either disable le spatial mapping component or disable the drawing of the wireframe on that same component in Inspector.